# how to use docker and salt provisioning

Tags: python, django, docker, salt, ansible

I am working on django project , I know python / django and worked some projects , but did not use any automated deployment tools like fabric,vagrant,anisible, puppet,chef ,salt.

Now I have a need to learn working with django using Docker and Salt provisioning.

Can any give brief intro to these things , mainly docker and salt.

what are the uses of each tools?

It will use full to beginners like me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Docker is an open platform for developers and sysadmins to build, ship, and run distributed applications. Take a look at https://www.docker.com/whatisdocker/ This explains what docker does.

Read https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/docker-explained-how-to-containerize-python-web-applications to get an idea of how to get started with Django on Docker.

Docker is really an amazing way to deploy anything. It's very simple as well. Feel free to get back if you are stuck on getting started.